# Javascript: Put the words from array between html tags

Tags: javascript, html, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a string as below:

`"Hello, world! I am posting a question on StackOverflow".`

I also have a list of words that I want to make bold in an HTML-like text as below:

`["Hello", "posting", "StackOverflow"]`

I want to get the result as follows:

`"<b>Hello<b/>, world! I am <b>posting<b/> a question on <b>StackOverflow<b/>."`

Bonus:

- It would be great to achieve this with a reliable library.
- Make the word matching case-insensitive.
- Support overlapping word matches.

Comment: What should happen in the following case. "abcdefghijklmnop" with ["cdefgh","def"]?

Comment: @ModestMonk Ideally I would expect to get "ab<b>cdefgh</b>ijklmnop". But I can live with "ab<b>c<b>def<b/>gh</b>ijklmnop" too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
let str = "Hello, world! I am posting a question on StackOverflow";
let strBoldArr = ["Hello", "posting", "StackOverflow"];
//split the string and iterate through each word
let strArr = str.split(/[ ]/).map((a) => {
  //check if word exists in the other array 
  if(strBoldArr.some(i => a.startsWith(i))){
    //check for character at the end
    if(a.endsWith(",")){
      //modify the string
      a = "<b>" + a.slice(0,-1) + "</b>, ";
    }
    else{
    //modify the string
      a = "<b>" + a + "</b>";
    }
  }
  return a;
}).join(" ");
console.log(strArr);
//test
document.write(strArr);
```